# Quando é/era usado o AbsoluteLayout?

Tags: android-layout

Sei que com esse *layout* é possível definir, manualmente, as posições `x` e `y` dos componentes inseridos no *layout*.

Em que hipótese é/era recomendado o uso do `AbsoluteLayout`, vez que trabalha com coordenadas fixas no plano, o que impossibilita uma boa visualização da `Activity` em outras resoluções?

Na versão do Android Studio que uso (Windows/2.3), quando tento usar esse *layout*, a IDE me traz uma mensagem dizendo que o mesmo é considerado obsoleto. Existe alguma alternativa à esse *layout*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), como você começou mencionar, permite especificar a localização exata de seus filhos. A localização das *views* pode ser especificada usando os atributos *layout* `x` e *layout* `y` ambos os valores são mencionados em `dip` ou `dp`(*density independent pixels*). Posicionamento absoluto não é muito útil no mundo de milhões de resoluções de tela e relações de aspecto, talvez por este motivo se tornou obsoleto.

A alternativa talvez mais viável para substituir o `AbsoluteLayout` seria mesmo o [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), onde em geral, você pode adicionar uma *view* em uma posição específica contendo como atributos o `leftMargin` e `topMargin`, que basicamente serviriam como suas coordenadas. Digamos que você precisa usar uma imagem de tamanho `40x40` na posição `80x100`, então você teria algo desta forma:

**Java**

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);    
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
params.leftMargin = 100;
params.topMargin  = 80;
frame.addView(iv, params);
```

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:background="#FFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

A imagem abaixo ilustra a visão referente ao `ImageView` e ao espaçamento. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3295056/2570426) no SO global que sugere como alternativa o `RelativeLayout`, porém particularmente talvez, digo talvez, não seja uma boa opção pois existem recursos do `RelativeLayout`, digamos assim, que basicamente seria inutilizados, fazendo com que não seja a melhor alternativa. Analogicamente você estaria levando canivete suíço para o bar apenas para usar abridor de cerveja.